# How to use stored procedure for crystal reports in asp.net MVC

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

Am trying to get `crystal report` using `stored procedure` in `MVC` but am getting the error is

> **(Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric)**

please help me how to fix this error

**My code is like this**

**SQL**

```
Create Proc SP_Rep_Sample
@ids varchar(MAX)
As
Begin
Select b.Name,a.Time,a.Date,a.Class,a.Price from T_Sample a
INNER JOIN T_Sample2 b on a.Fk_Tid=b.Pk_Tid 
where Pk_Id IN (SELECT Value FROM Fn_Split(@ids, ','))
End
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult RepTicket()
{
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Report/RepTicket.rpt")));
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"].ToString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Rep_Sample'"+Globals.bookedids+"'", cn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sda.Fill(dt);
rd.SetDataSource(dt);
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Stream str =      rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
str.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
return File(str, "application/pdf", "Ticket.pdf");
}
```

Comment: what is datatype for `Pk_Id` ? and `Value` from `Fn_Split` functions?

Comment: numeric(18, 0) .... the value like '1,2,3'

Comment: value is coming from which table..@Raviteja

Comment: T_Sample the first table the id is scope identity....

Comment: @Raviteja add your query with sample data here http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: What is the output of Fn_Split(@ids, ',') is it csv or a table with id's? I suggest to use a split function that 1. trim the values and then insert then into a table.